# Idiomatic way to write firstRightOrLefts in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, either

I have the following method:

```
firstRightOrLefts :: [Either b a] -> Either [b] a
firstRightOrLefts eithers = 
   case partitionEithers eithers of
      (_,  (x : _)) -> Right x
      (xs, _)       -> Left xs
```

What bothers me is the ugly pattern matching and I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way to write this method. The idea is that I have a bunch of computations that can return Eithers and I just want to get the first result or all of the error messages. Maybe I'm using the wrong data structure. Maybe the Writer monad would be better suited to this task. I'm really not sure at this point. Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reverse convention is actually just the monad definition for `Either` and the definition for `sequence` is adequate for this:

```
ghci> :t sequence :: [Either a b] -> Either a [b]
sequence :: [Either a b] -> Either a [b]
  :: [Either a b] -> Either a [b]
```

To actually apply this to your case we'd therefore need a function flipEither:

```
firstRightOrLefts = fe . sequence . map fe
    where fe (Left a) = Right a
          fe (Right b) = Left b
```

Comment: That is actually a brilliant answer, it's simple and concise. Leaving it open for one more day just in case there is a simpler answer out there but otherwise I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: I mean, you can also write yours as `firstRightOrLefts = go [] where go acc e = case e of [] -> Left (reverse acc); (Right r):es -> Right r; (Left l):es -> go (l:acc) es` if you want. What I really like about the above answer is that it reveals that you're probably using the Either monad (at least in this operation) in a way opposite to how people normally do: since you want to accumulate errors and stop on the first success, your use-case is flipped compared to people who want to stop on the first error. It probably doesn't matter but if you're writing a parser, that's useful to know!

Comment: You can also write `fe = either Right Left`.

Answer (score 9):

The `MonadPlus` instance for [`Except`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) has this behaviour:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

firstRightOrLefts :: [Either e a] -> Either [e] a
firstRightOrLefts = runExcept . msum . fmap (withExcept (:[]) . except)
```

Comment: That's pretty nice. Especially since it uses standard operators to do the work. I'm going to follow the types further to see how it does what it does.